# Run Tomcat simultaneously in multiple workspaces in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, localhost, tomcat6, workspace

I have two different workspaces in Eclipse and in both both workspaces I have configured same Tomcat web server. Now when i run a web app on server from one workspace I cant run the other app on server from other workspace.
I want to keep my projects in different workspaces and want to run them simultaneously on localhost. How can i do this ? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click the Tomcat server in the `Servers` view. You'll see an overview in the editor that allows you to alter the ports. Make sure you assign a different set of ports for each instance.

Comment: it says "Port 8009 required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."

Comment: Yes, that's why I told you to set different ports in each workspace.

Comment: i used port 8888 for one workspace and 8080 for the other. one started and running succesfully other is showing above error

Comment: @Rizstien, remember I said "assign a different _set_"? All three ports must be unique because Tomcat binds to all of them.

Comment: Hurrahhh.... it is working perfect now I am editing your answer to mention set of all three ports and marking it as accepted. Thanks @Marcel